# Strange/Magical Image visualization with Matlab

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, png

I have an Image of double, I want to show it with unsigned int 16 bit, so I do:

```
I = im2uint16(I);
figure;imshow(I);title('Image being saved')
```

This shows this (with its normal noise):

[image]

Now I want to write this image with .png with Bit Depth 16 Bit. I do:

```
imwrite(I,'image.png','BitDepth',16);
```

And now the image, opened with Photoshop CS5, or Windows Photo Viwer looks like this:  (the noise is magically disappeared):

[image]

Can someone explain this strange behaviour ?

### How to Reproduce this error

Download in `C:\test\` the [image I used here](https://p7o1zg.bay.livefilestore.com/y1pcQVsmssygbS4BLW24_X1E09BKt_Im-2yAxXBqWesC47gpv5bdFZf962T4it1roSaJkz5ChLBS0cxzQe6JfjDNrF7x-Cc12x8/test_matlab.tif?psid=1):

Now run this script:

```
I = im2double(imread('C:\test\test_matlab.tif'));

% Add gaussian noise with variance = 0.0012
I = imnoise(I,'gaussian',0,0.0012);
figure,imshow(I);

imwrite(I,'C:\test\withNoise.tif');
```

And compare the figure in matlab versus the file saved

Comment: I cannot reproduce this on R2013a with `I = repmat(linspace(0,1,512),512,1);
I = I+randn(size(I))*0.1;
I16 = im2uint16(I);
imwrite(I16,'test.png','BitDepth',16)`, and opening in either IrfanView or Photoshop CS4

Comment: I cannot reproduce it on R2012b, either.

Comment: Can you share the original data with us?

Comment: just to make sure, when you use `imshow`, are you using a default matlab colormap (64 colors) or what photoshop uses (256 colors)...

Comment: If this issue cannot be reproduced - I vote to close.

Comment: i will share with you my data. please wait

Comment: Please all, I have added the source image and the script to reproduce the error in my question

Comment: @Natan: how do I use the colormap that photoshop uses in matlab?

Comment: The source image you posted does not resemble your "clean" image at all, it looks like pure noise.

Comment: @leonbloy In my hands, it looks quite nice.

Comment: @Jonas: true, it was a problem of my viewer (xnView)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's difficult to say because you didn't give enough data to reproduce, but I'd guess the problem is related to a display issue: the image is larger than you physical display window, hence some downsampling must be applied to display it. Depending on how that resampling is done, the result can be -in this scenario- very different, visually.
Suppose that matlab applies a nearest-neighbour resampling for its display, that would explain why the image looks very noisy; instead, if another image viewer applies a bilinear interpolation or something similar, that would amount to a local average that practically filters out the white noise.

To test this, try the same with a small image. Or try zooming the apparently clean image, to see it at real size (100% : one image pixel = one display pixel)

*Update*: See also [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/323870)

Comment: I've come to the same conclusion, but you explained it better - +1.

Comment: @leonbloy: I have posted in the question the image and script used for tests

Comment: @llnk : did you try what I say in my last paragraph?

Comment: @leonbloy: If I zoom in from photoshop or Windows Viewer it seems I see much more noise, but I think that's normal (zoom in = more noise)

Comment: Anyway can I force matlab to use bilinear interpolation while downsampling ?

Comment: @llnk : "If I zoom in from photoshop or Windows Viewer it seems I see much more noise, but I think that's normal (zoom in = more noise)" Well, no. Just compare with the original image.

Comment: @leonbloy: I was confirming your thesis, I meant see much more noise than the zoomed-out image (with the bilinear interpolation or whatever)

Comment: @llnk: call [imresize](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imresize.html) before displaying the image

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I did:

```
%# read the image (why is it so big?)
I = im2double(imread('https://p7o1zg.bay.livefilestore.com/y1pcQVsmssygbS4BLW24_X1E09BKt_Im-2yAxXBqWesC47gpv5bdFZf962T4it1roSaJkz5ChLBS0cxzQe6JfjDNrF7x-Cc12x8/test_matlab.tif?psid=1'));

%# add noise
I = imnoise(I,'gaussian',0,0.0012);

%# write tiff
imwrite(I,'withNoise.tif');

%# read the tiff again
I2 = imread('withNoise.tif');

class(I2) %# -- oopsie, it's uint8 now! 

%# convert to uint16 as in original post
I = im2uint16(I);

%# writ again
imwrite(I,'withNoise16.png','bitDepth',16);

%# read it
I2 = imread('withNoise16.png');

%# compare
all(all(I==I2)) %# everything is equal
```

So there is no funky stuff going on in writing/reading the image (though you lose some information in the bit conversion - your original image only takes up about a third of the dynamic range, so you'll lose more information that if you stretched the contrast before conversion).

However, the image is 2k-by-2k. When I only look at the top right corner of the image (taking 500-by-500 pix), it is displayed the same in Matlab and other graphics programs. So I bet it's a matter of resampling your image that Matlab does differently from other programs. As @leonbloy suggests, Matlab may be doing nearest-neighbor resampling, while other programs would do interpolation.

Comment: Thanks +1. If you look at the whole image (without looking at the top right corner) do you confirm that you see lots of noise while if you write it and open it with a software you don't see it ?

Comment: @llnk: When I write and open in Matlab, I don't see any difference. When I open with another software and *do not* zoom in, there appears to be less noise.

Comment: exectly what I saw in my question